# Does AcquireTokenForClient (MSAL) use the token cache?

Tags: c#, azure-ad-msal

I am (successfully) using client credential flow with MSAL to authenticate an app like this:

```
private static async Task<AuthenticationResult> getAuthResultNonInteractively()
{
    string[] scopes = {"api://xxx/.default"};

    IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.CreateWithApplicationOptions(
            new ConfidentialClientApplicationOptions
            {
                TenantId = "xxx",
                ClientId = "xxx",
                RedirectUri = "http://localhost",
                ClientSecret = "xxx"
            })
        .Build();
    
    // Desired behaviour: acquires token online only if token does not 
    // exist in cache or is expired
    AuthenticationResult authResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
        .ExecuteAsync();

    return authResult;
}
```

Does the call to `AcquireTokenForClient` first try to find the token in the token cache, and acquires it online only if the token doesn't exist in the cache yet or the token is expired? Or does it always acquire the token online? If the latter is true, what do I need to change in order to get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `AppTokenCache` used by `AcquireTokenForClient` is associated with your specific instance of `IConfidentialClientApplication`, so in order to take advantage of token caching, your `IConfidentialClientApplication` will need to be **long-lived** (i.e. **singleton**).

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-token-cache-serialization?tabs=aspnet

```
public static async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetTokenAsync(string clientId, X509Certificate cert, string authority, string[] scopes)
 {
     // Create the confidential client application
     app= ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
       // Alternatively to the certificate, you can use .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
       .WithCertificate(cert)
       .WithLegacyCacheCompatibility(false)
       .WithAuthority(authority)
       .Build();

     // Add a static in-memory token cache. Other options available: see below
     app.AddInMemoryTokenCache();  // Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenCache 1.17+
   
     // Make the call to get a token for client_credentials flow (app-to-app scenario) 
     return await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
     
     // OR Make the call to get a token for OBO (web API scenario)
     return await app.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(scopes, userAssertion).ExecuteAsync();
     
     // OR Make the call to get a token via auth code (web app scenario)
     return await app.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopes, authCode);    
     
     // OR, when the user has previously logged in, get a token silently
     string homeAccountId = User.GetHomeAccountId(); // uid and utid claims
     var account = await app.GetAccountAsync(homeAccountId);
     try
     {
          return await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, account).ExecuteAsync();; 
     } 
     catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
     {
        // cannot get a token silently, so redirect the user to be challenged 
     }
  }
```