# Why socket handles are leaked

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, webapi

I have a .Net Core web app deployed to Azure App Service. The API has only one endpoint, and all it does is call another API (inside `MyCLass`) and return the response.

I have the following in my Startup:

```
services.AddScoped<IOAuthService, OAuthService>();
services.AddHttpClient<IMyClass, MyClass>(client =>
{
    var authConfig = config.Get<OAuthConfig>();
    var oAuthService = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IOAuthService>();

    var token = oAuthService.GetTokenAsync(authConfig).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
});
```

And here is the `OAuthService.GetTokenAsync` method:

```
private IConfidentialClientApplication app;
public async Task<string> GetTokenAsync(OAuthConfig config)
{
    app ??= ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(config.ClientId)
        .WithTenantId(config.TenantId)
        .WithClientSecret(config.ClientSecret)
        .WithLegacyCacheCompatibility(false) // No need to share with ADAL.NET; increases performance
        .Build();

    var scopes = new string[] { $"{config.Resource}/.default" };
    var authResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
        .ExecuteAsync()
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    return authResult.AccessToken;
}
```

A `HttpClient` is injected into `MyClass` where it calls another API and returns the response. The above code results in socket handle leaks and SNAT port exhaustion.

However, the following changes would solve the problem: 1. Instead of getting the token once in DI, get the token in `MyCLass` on the fly every time a request is made (without any changes to `OAuthService`). 2. Changing the above DI code to the following:

```
services.AddSingleton<IOAuthService, OAuthService>();
services.AddHttpClient<IHdcApiDataConnector, HdcApiDataConnector>();
```

My question is why exactly the second code solves the socket handle leak problem?

Comment: I'm not in that world as much, but both look wrong to me. Computing and validating tokens is designed to be expensive; it needs to be, otherwise they'd be easy to crack. This means you don't want to do it again on every request. But they also tend to have short life times, so at the same time you don't want to just assume the token created at startup is still correct.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn a singleton `ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder` would do the caching of tokens for you (see my answer for a link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my question.

Ok after some investigation, I found out what was happening:

1. Using `??==` was an attempt to make sure `ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder` is created only once. However, registering `IOAuthService` as scoped means a new instance is created for every incoming request and hence one `ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder` is created in each instance. Making it singleton in the second approach would solve this issue.
2. `services.AddHttpClient<IMyClass, MyClass>` registers `IMyClass` [as transient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientfactoryservicecollectionextensions.addhttpclient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-httpclientfactoryservicecollectionextensions-addhttpclient-2(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-system-string-system-action((system-net-http-httpclient)))). This means a new instance of `MyClass` is created for each incoming request. Further, for every such instance, the code `services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IOAuthService>()` creates another instance of `IOAuthService` causing the problem mentioned above.

Aside from the DI issue, there are some other issues with my code above:

1. As @JoelCoehoorn mentioned in the comments, there is another big flaw in the first approach: tokens expire and should be refreshed.
2. `app ??= ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create` should probably be moved to either the constructor or even in DI, it's very confusing and error-prone to have that kind of logic (making sure the `ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder` is singleton) inside the class method.

Further, note that if the `ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder` is singleton, then the tokens are cached under the hood and you don't have to implement *refreshing* tokens yourself ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65887066/does-acquiretokenforclient-msal-use-the-token-cache)).